# ARRAYFORMULA - How to reference previous column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Lets say I have a row where's there's a % increase based on the value in the previous Column so

A1 = 1
B1 = A1*1.1
C1 = B1*1.1
....
G1 = F1*1.1

Is there an ARRAYFORMULA that can be entered into B1 that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pnuts's answer can be improved upon and made to work by actually deleting part of his formula:

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula(1.1^row(1:10)*A$1))
```

[image]

Comment: @pnuts - Both formulas make complete sense how they work. Since it's raising the multiple to the column number. This puts me on the right track. Now I'm going to try to adjust the formula so no matter if a new row / column is created the values will always be the same. My objective is to create a formula that won't break when the sheet is adjusted. I'm guessing some type OFFSET will have to come into play here in some way. Thanks to both of you for helping get me on the right track!

Comment: @pnuts Indeed with column() it's formally simpler but not as clear IMO, because with row() you clearly see, or can specify, how many values you're getting (10) and with column() you're working with letters, not numbers